# Turn off date suggestions in Reminders?

Tags: macos, ios, reminders

I often include numbers as I write Reminders entries, I almost never include a date or time in the reminder title (there is a date field after all). Nonetheless Reminders very earnestly suggests dates and times to me as I create each Reminder item. It bugs me...

Is there any way (a `defaults` setting perhaps) to disable this behavior? I've already submitted feedback.

Comment: Have you considered creating a [shortcut](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208309) for adding reminders? You can also disable the keyboard suggestions (“Predictive” toggle in Keyboard settings), if you don’t want them at all.

Comment: @JBallin, thanks, both of those seem like ideas to check out. Just checked and on Catalina (10.15.6beta) I don't see a Predictive toggle in the Keyboard settings.

Comment: Ah my comment was actually iPhone specific.